# Facebook API: IM Screen Names

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I get the user's IM Screen Names (e.g. Yahoo! Messenger, Skype, AOL) using Graph API or FQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Facebook user's screennames are not available through the Graph API or FQL. See [this thread from Facebook's forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=93135), where a Facebook employee confirms this fact.